# SwiftUI: Conditional commands on the Scene

Tags: if-statement, swiftui

I'm trying to create commands (system menu line) that will be shown related to some condition. But looks like this is impossible for commands.

Can somebody help me?

Sample:

```
WindowGroup {
   SomeView()
}
.commands {
    if (true) {
        CustomMenu()
    }
}
```

Error: Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'CommandsBuilder'

---

```
struct CustomMenu: Commands {
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandMenu("CustomMenu") {
            Button("Print message") {
                print("Hello World!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your expected output behaviour with screen shot or with more explanation

Comment: ok, I need conditional behaviour. If some bool is true - need to display menu. If false - do not need to display "CustomMenu" menu. this just a sample that shows that conditional commands is impossible.

Comment: @Jessy you didn't tried those solution, but you telling me that it is works. But I have already tried before ask the question - those solution cannot work because of `Commands` IS NOT `View`. `View` have `@ViewBuilder`, but `Commands` have no `@CommandsBuilder`. That's why those solution cannot work even theoretically. And that's why conditions does not work in `Commands`, but works in `View`.

Comment: @Jessy And `Scene` have no `@SceneBuilder`. That's why you cannot write conditional apply of `.commands{ }` modifier. And `WindowGroup` is a `some Scene`, but NOT `some View`. Scene is not View. Scene is a SORT OF VIEWS that can be shown as set of windows.  So no, those "duplicate" is NOT solution of my question. And before downvote or mark any question as duplicate you must be SURE that this is duplicate question. But not THINK that it is.

Comment: Huh. You're almost right. `SceneBuilder.buildEither` is specifically what's missing, and there's no `AnyScene` type to use in order to implement it.

Answer (score -2):

this compiles, but creates an "empty" menu .... maybe there is a way to "hide" this empty menu somewhere.

```
@State private var condition = true

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
    .commands {
        CommandMenu(condition ? "CustomMenu" : "") {
            if condition {
                Button("Print message") {
                    print("Hello World!")
                    condition = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```